# How to compare one row of a numpy array to all the other rows

Tags: python, numpy, enumerate

I have a numpy array with some coordinates (`x`,`y` and `z`):

```
coord=np.array([[0.,0.,2.], [0.,1.,3.], [0.,2.,2.], [1.,0.,1.], [1.,1.,3.], [2.,0.,1.], [2.,1.,1.], [3.,0.,1.]])
threshold = 1
```

I want to compare each row of this array with all the next row. Then, in case of satisfying my condition, I want to print the number of rows which the condition is satisfied. I tried the following but it is only comparing one row with the next one rather than all the rows:

```
for ind, val in enumerate (coord):
    if coord[ind][1] == coord[ind+1][1] and coord[ind+1][0]-coord[ind][1] < 1.2 * threshold:
        print (ind+13, ind+1+14)
```

I want to start from the first row and check it with all the following rows. Then I want to check the second row with all the following ones and so on. In my condition I want to say if the the present row has the same `y` value (`coord[:,1]`) with the next ones and also their `x` distance (`coord[ind+1][0]-coord[ind][1]`) is not more than a threshold, print the index of that two pairs (my code call them `ind+13`, `ind+1+13` which is not correct, because I want to add 13 to index of the detected pairs). Finally I want to print such a result:

```
13, 16
14, 17
16, 18
17, 19
18, 20
```

I appreciate any help and contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a second loop through your values behind the one you are currently lokking at:

```
for ind, val in enumerate (coord):
    if ind < len(coord): 
        for ind1, val1 in enumerate (coord[ind+1:]):
            if val[1] == val1[1] and (abs((val[0] - val1[0])) < (1.2 * threshold)):
                print (ind+13, ind+ind1+14)
```

Comment: Dear @KaRaOkEy, I do appreciate your solution. But it is not giving me the correct answer. When I try it, it gives me 12 pairs but I expected to have only five pairs. The pairs also are not correct.

Comment: In this case, your questions was not specific enough I think.
I edited my answer ;)

If I understand correct now, you want the absolut difference (coordinates). If not, feel free to comment again.

Answer (score 2):

When working with NumPy arrays, it is often much more efficient to use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) approaches than Python loops. Here is a solution to your problem that uses broadcasting, and results in an array of the desired indices:

```python
# Compute all indices that meet the conditions
i, j = np.where(
    (coord[:, 1] == coord[:, np.newaxis, 1]) &
    (abs(coord[:, 0] - coord[:, np.newaxis, 0]) < 1.2 * threshold)
)

# Restrict to where i is before j
i, j = i[i < j], j[i < j]

# Combine and print the indices, with 13 added
print(np.vstack([i, j]).T + 13)
# [[13 16]
#  [14 17]
#  [16 18]
#  [17 19]
#  [18 20]]
```